# Got an error while implementing express session

Tags: node.js, express

I want to implement session in my app. Here's my code:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var swig = require('swig');
var session = require('express-sessions');
var helmet = require('helmet');
var login = require('./routes/login');
var edit_profil = require('./routes/manajemen_profil');
var manajemen_venue = require('./routes/manajemen_venue');
var manajemen_akun = require('./routes/manajemen_list_akun');
var manajemen_event = require('./routes/manajemen_event');
var manajemen_list_email = require('./routes/manajemen_list_email');


var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.engine('html', swig.renderFile);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'html');

//security reason
app.use(helmet());

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));


app.use('/', login);
app.use('/edit_profil', edit_profil);
app.use('/manajemen_venue', manajemen_venue);
app.use('/manajemen_list_akun', manajemen_akun);
app.use('/manajemen_event', manajemen_event);
app.use('/manajemen_list_email', manajemen_list_email);

//Session
app.use(session({
  secret: 'fffdfee',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
}));

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('notfound');
});
//test
module.exports = app;
```

But it returned error:

> C:\Users\User\Desktop\manajemen-event-master\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:210
>       throw new TypeError('app.use() requires middleware functions');
>       ^
>
> TypeError: app.use() requires middleware functions
>       at EventEmitter.use (C:\Users\User\Desktop\manajemen-event-master\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:210:11)
>       at Object. (C:\Users\User\Desktop\manajemen-event-master\app.js:45:5)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
>       at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
>       at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
>       at Object. (C:\Users\User\Desktop\manajemen-event-master\bin\www:7:11)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
>       at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)

Can you help me how to solve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have made a typo in the module name.The module is `express-session`, but your require statement is loading `express-sessions`.